# Implementing the openPanel() method of the MatAutocompleteTrigger

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to open the suggestion panel on a keyup.ArrowDown event. If the down arrow button is depressed then I want to display all the values in my auto suggestion panel

Here is my code example. I have found various examples of this method on SO but none seem to work in my scenario.

```
 <form class="declarationType">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="typeCtrl" (keyup.ArrowDown)="openAutocomplete($event)">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [panelWidth]="700" >
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let type of declarationTypes$ | async" [value]="type.value" class="comboBox" >
        <span>{{type.value}}</span> |
        <small>{{type.declarationTypeCodeDescription}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  </form>

 @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) inputAutoComplit: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
......
 openAutocomplete() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.inputAutoComplit.openPanel();
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: did you try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyup-open-panel-9wnnpr is it your requirement?

Comment: I had tried that one, thanks. Finally figured it out. I was binding to the declarationTypes$ property which is an observable I use when invoking valueChanges on the form control, and also invoking the async pipe. I should have bound to the declarationTypes property witch is not an observable

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that the `input` has to be focused for `(keyup.ArrowDown)` to fire... if you think about this, autocomplete already opens when you click inside of the `input` and defeats the purpose of using `(keyup.ArrowDown)`.

The following will only work after you have clicked inside the `input`, which will open the `autoComplete`, and then click `ArrowDown`.

```
openAutocomplete() {
    console.log('ArrowDown Clicked')
  }
```

What you are looking for is a listener at the document level for `ArrowDown` which will open the `autoComplete` without the `input` having focus.

Grab a reference to the `MatAutocompleteTrigger`

```
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material'

@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) _auto: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Setup a `HostListener` to call `openPanel()` when it sees the `ArrowDown` key event.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
      this._auto.openPanel();
    }
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

You will need to click in the white area below the input in this stackblitz to focus the document (do not click/focus the input only the document) and then press `ArrowDown` to open the `autoComplete`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtepne?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts